# How to setup environment variables to run sattools?

Tags: 20.04

Yeah I was trying to install SATTOOLS by Cees BASSA the other day and ran into a problem. I couldn’t setup environment variables to run SATTOOLS.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In `bash` or `sh`, you can set environment variables for the current session (if on the shell prompt) or all future sessions (if in `~/.bashrc`) using the following command:

```
export KEY=value
```

In your case, you would set `ST_COSPAR=` something as described in that picture that you linked in your post (that I regrettably can't read due to it being very zoomed in), and the other environment variables as described as well.

This question's answers may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234742/setting-environment-variables-in-linux-using-bash